# Unknown film from my childhood: "red mine" with post-apocalyptic futuristic vibe

Tags: story-identification, movie

When I was about 3 years old I remember watching a very strange film. There was this peculiar "red mine" (as I call it), with a kind of post-apocalyptic futuristic vibe. I also remember that in this "mine" (I actually don't remember for what purpose the supposed "mine" was actually used in the film) there were prisoners, clothed a bit like desert maniacs from Mad Max, or at least it seemed that they were there for some involuntary work. The last thing I can remember are some large wood pillars on which different kinds of linen, they closely resembled nomad tents. I very faintly remember very tall machines, the shape of which I forgot. The film is from the time period 1980—2004.

And that's about it. Please, if you know any film that my description closely resembles, let me know about it. All answers are greatly appreciated.

P.S. The described is only **a portion of the film** (about 20 minutes I think), so keep an open mind about it. Furthermore, it **is possible** that the described scene is from a film I *do* know but just don't remember this particular portion.

Comment: Maybe the original Total Recall Movie? Near the end Arnold enters some ancient cave an mars where ragged mutants are hiding. This could be your "red mine" and "maniacs from Mad Max". And later there are large pillars and machines:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zPPWOtlxA0A

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6MRRMgeOZqs

Comment: @Hothie Thank you for the suggestion! Although I've already found a very likely source: an obscure film called *No Escape* (1994). It has all the components I remember though I could be wrong. Thank you again!

Comment: @GregorPerčič - if you've found the answer, please leave a self-answer below! After 48 hours, you'll be able to accept it.

Comment: @Mithrandir Ummm, I'm not quite sure that my guess is the right answer, so I won't do that just yet.

Comment: @GregorPerčič any more input on _No Escape_? Was it the one or does the search continue? :)

Comment: @Jenayah Well, I was really young when I (supposedly) viewed this film, so I can't remember well. It is, however, the best candidate for that film I've been able to find.